# CKEDITOR - Prevent Page refresh on clicking 'Save' Button on Toolbar and call own function

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

How Can we call our own function on **save** button click in Toolbar? Also it currently refreshes the page on clicking save button, how can we prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKEDITOR fires a *save event* when toolbar save button is clicked. We need to listen to it.

To prevent page refresh we need to add

```
return false;
```

to our listener callback function. **Example:**

**HTML**

```
<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">--</textarea>
```

**JS**

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' ); //Replace text area with CKEditor

CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on( 'save', function( evt ) {    
        alert(evt.editor.getData());
        return false; //Prevents Page Refresh
        });
```